# How to safely delete the contents of a folder with a bash script?

Tags: bash

I would like to automate the build process in my project folder. I have a local `./build` and I run `cmake ..` inside it. However, before every build, I would like to flush the contents of that `./build` folder. Below is my script that I have came up with so far, and it works, however, I am a bit worried that it might get out of control and delete something crucial. What is the best way to ensure the most secure way for deleting the contents of a folder?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Store project's root path.
_currentPath="$PWD"
_buildFolderTag='build'

# Dive into the build folder, if it exists.
if [ -d ${_currentPath}/${_buildFolderTag} ]; then
    # Use the -i flag to first check what files are deleted.
    # Then remove that from the command.
    # We would like to run "rm -rf ./build/*" 
    rm -rf ./${_buildFolderTag}/*
    # Get inside the ./build folder
    cd ${_currentPath}/${_buildFolderTag}
    # Run cmake in there.
    cmake ..
    # Return to project's root.
    cd $_currentPath
fi
```

Comment: The best way to safely delete files and folders with a script is to *remove* write permission on the files and folders you want to keep from the user running the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_buildFolderTag` is fixed in your script, so it should not go out of `build` subfolder, ever.

You may check what is `.` currently. It prevents deleting `my_crucial_dir/build` instead of `my_daily_build/build`.

---

You can use [trash-cli](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli) instead of `rm`.

On Ubuntu, it is in the repo: `sudo apt-get install trash-cli`

throw files to trash: `trash-put file1`

Once, you should empty the trash: `trash-empty`

If it is a production script, the user would not be happy with something gone to trash. But you can echo the full path to the user and ask for confirmation:

```
answer=""
echo "Confirm deleting the build folder: "$(pwd)${_buildFolderTag}
while [[ "$answer" != "y" && "$answer" != "n" ]]
do
  read -p "Your choice (y/n): " answer
done
if [[ "$answer" == "y" ]]
then
  rm -rf ./${_buildFolderTag}/*
fi
```

Comment: Anchoring the script with an absolute path (either in setting `_currentPath` or otherwise) can help avoid mistaken deletes as well. (`$PWD` isn't quite the perfect choice since it will provide a relative absolute path)